# How can I make a LINQ query with subqueries in the from statement?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Can I make this type of SQL query on LINQ to SQL?

(this query is only a example)

```
select *
from orders as o
left outer join (select * from ordersdetail where status = 'A') as od
on o.id = od.orderid
```

What I need is how can I put a subquery inside de "from" statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the order details condition in the usual way:

```
from o in orders
join od from orderdetails on o.id = od.orderid
  into details
where details.status == 'A'
select new { Order = o, Details = details}
```

(NB. Details is a sequence, with each matching details record, LINQ operators like First and FirstOrDefault can be use to extract just one.)

Or use an expression as the data source

```
from o in orders
join od from orderdetails.Where(d => d.Status == 'A') on o.id = od.orderid
  into details
select new { Order = o, Details = details}
```

Or even, use another comprehension expression as the source expression:

```
from o in orders
join od from (from d in orderdetails
              where d.Status == 'A'
              select d)
  on o.id = od.orderid
  into details
select new { Order = o, Details = details}
```

(Setting you `DataContext`'s `Log` property allows you to see the SQL so you can compare what SQL is actually generated.)

EDIT: Change to use Group Join (`... into var`) to get the outer join (rather than an inner join).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with the Where function:

```
from o in orders
join od in ordersdetail.Where(x => x.status == 'A') on o.id = od.orderid
select new { Order = o, Details = od}
```